# probability at least one child finds their pair of gloves

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Their are 4 pairs of gloves, $8$ gloves in total. $4$ children whose gloves are in the pile randomly select $2$ gloves.

What would the probability be that at least one child selects his pair of gloves?

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Can you at least share where you are stuck ? Thanks

Comment: I guess I dont understand the theory behind this. I think the inclusion-exclusion principle is important for this question, Im having a hard time understanding how to apply it especially since it asks for specific "pairs" and not just selecting one item

Answer (score 2):

Welcome Emily.  Yes, PIE is the way to go.

Let $A,B,C,D$ be the events that Ada, Ben, Carl, and Danae find their own gloves.  These events are, of course, *dependent*.

Then $\def\Pr{\mathsf P}\Pr(A),\Pr(B),\Pr(C),\Pr(D)$ are the probabilities that one particular child finds their glove (and they are all equal), $\Pr(A,B),\Pr(A,C),\Pr(A,D),\Pr(B,C),\Pr(B,D),\Pr(C,D)$ the probabities that two particular children do so (and are likewise equal to each other), and so on.

Thus by the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion you seek $$\binom 41\Pr(A)-\binom 42\Pr(A,B)+\binom 43\Pr(A,B,C)-\binom 44\Pr(A,B,C,D)$$

**To do:** Evaluate those probabilities.

> Okay, one is $\mathsf P(A,B)=\dfrac{1}{\binom 82\binom 62}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Look for the case when none of the children find pair calculate the probability and subtract from 1

Read this : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: I still don't understand how to find this

Comment: You are looking for dearrangement

Answer (score 0):

Simple method is to first compute probability that nobody gets the right pair and then substarct it from 1. Before procedding i will assume that gloves are kept in pair.  Suppose that threre are four child $A, B, C, D$. 
Then,
 *Probability that $A$ gets wrong pair of gloves =* $\frac{3}{4}$
*Probability that $B$ gets wrong pair of gloves =* $\frac{2}{3}$
*Probability that $C$ gets wrong pair of gloves =* $\frac{1}{2}$
And finally $D$ will left with no choice.

Now, *let $E$ = No child gets right pair of gloves*
then,
$$P(E) = \frac{3}{4}×\frac{2}{3}×\frac{1}{2}$$
$$P(E) = \frac{1}{4}$$
*Probability that atleast one child gets right pair of gloves =*$ 1 - P(E) = \frac{3}{4}$

Comment: I don't think this question assumes that the gloves are kept in pairs, though.